# Why is While (rs.next()) statement ending after 1st iteration?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, while-loop, resultset

I am using a SELECT statement to get data from a table and then insert it into another table.  However the line "stmt.executeQuery(query);" is inserting the first line from the table then exits.  When I comment this line out, the while loop loops through all the lines printing them out.  The stacktrace isn't showing any errors.  Why is this happening?

```
try{                
    String query = "SELECT * FROM "+schema_name+"."+table;

    rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

    while (rs.next()) {

        String bundle = rs.getString("BUNDLE");
        String project_cd = rs.getString("PROJECT_CD");
        String dropper = rs.getString("DROPPER");
        String week = rs.getString("WEEK");
        String drop_dt = rs.getString("DROP_DT").replace(" 00:00:00.0","");

        query = "INSERT INTO INDUCTION_INFO (BUNDLE, PROJECT_CD, DROPPER, WEEK, DROP_DT) "
              + "VALUES ("
              + bundle+","
              + "'"+project_cd+"',"
              + dropper+","
              + week+","
              + "to_date('"+drop_dt+"','YYYY-MM-DD'))";

        System.out.println(query);

        stmt.executeQuery(query);
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Hm ... actually I don't know if calling `executeUpdate()` on a statement closes that statements previous `ResultSet`. And I'm too lazy to test that right now ...

Comment: The specific question is answered already, but as an observation: you should be using a prepared statement and changing the bind variables each time instead of build a new insert with the values hard-coded in. (It seems like an unlikely place to get an SQL injection, but depends who can put entries in the source table...). But why not just do it in one hit with a select-as-insert, instead of looping?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are re-using the `Statement` that was used to produce `rs` on the last line of your loop.

This will close the `ResultSet` `rs`. As [stated in the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html):

> A `ResultSet` object is automatically closed when the `Statement` object that generated it is closed, re-executed, or used to retrieve the next result from a sequence of multiple results.

You need to use a second `Statement` object to execute the `INSERT` statements.

Answer (score 9):

`Statement` objects can only do one thing at a time, so when you execute that `INSERT`, you invalidate the `ResultSet` which it generated.  You'll need to create a second `Statement` object to perform the `INSERT`.

From the [Statement documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html): "By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one ResultSet object is interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated by different Statement objects. All execution methods in the Statement interface implicitly close a statment's current ResultSet object if an open one exists."

Answer (score 1):

if you use the same statement, it will invalidate the previous result set. You should use a different statement to perform updates/inserts.

Answer (score 1):

This is from the Java docs of interface [Statement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html):

> By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open
>   at the same time.

So you better use a second `Statement` or even better a `PreparedStatement`.

And to execute an INSERT SQL statement you should use `executeUpdate()` instead of `executeQuery()`.