# Insert values using a loop

Tags: java, database, resultset

I have a database column with 54 values.I want to create a table for each values.But my code only creates first value table then it shows an error due to closing `ResultSet`.

How can I reopen the `ResultSet` using a loop? I need all 54 valued tables.

Code:

```
public void createTableStudent() {
    try {
        connection = (Connection) dbSource.getConnection();

        String qry = "SELECT studentName From batcha "; 
        System.out.println(qry);

        stmt = (PreparedStatement)  connection.prepareStatement(qry);
            rs =  stmt.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {

                String check=new String(rs.getString(("studentName")));
                String student = check.replaceAll("\\s","");

                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL_table, USER, PASS);

                String sql1 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+student+" " +
                    "(id INTEGER not NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, " +
                    " fcltyName VARCHAR(255), " + 

                    "CommunicationOral INTEGER, "+
                    "Communicationwritten INTEGER, "+
                    "Leadership INTEGER, "+
                    "AnalyticalAbilities INTEGER, "+
                    "Interpersonalskills INTEGER, "+
                    "DecisionMakingSkills INTEGER, "+
                    "SelfConfidence INTEGER, "+
                    "Creativity INTEGER, "+
                    "Punctualityregularity INTEGER, "+
                    "GeneralAwareness INTEGER, "+
                    "Commitment INTEGER, "+
                    "Hardwork INTEGER, "+

                    " PRIMARY KEY ( id ))"; 
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql1); 

                        }



    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AdminHome.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AdminHome.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

It shows following error

```
 java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This violates the expectation of the [Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) class.

> By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open
>   at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one ResultSet object is
>   interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated
>   by different Statement objects. All execution methods in the Statement
>   interface implicitly close a statment's current ResultSet object if an
>   open one exists.

So you need to create a new `Statement` for table creation.

```
public void createTableStudent() 
{
    try {
        connection = (Connection) dbSource.getConnection();

        String qry = "SELECT studentName From batcha "; 
        System.out.println(qry);

        stmt = (PreparedStatement)  connection.prepareStatement(qry);
            rs =  stmt.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) 
            {

                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL_table, USER, PASS);

                Statement newStmt = connection.createStatement();

                try {
                        String check=new String(rs.getString(("studentName")));
                        String student = check.replaceAll("\\s","");



                        String sql1 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+student+" " +
                            "(id INTEGER not NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, " +
                            " fcltyName VARCHAR(255), " + 

                            "CommunicationOral INTEGER, "+
                            "Communicationwritten INTEGER, "+
                            "Leadership INTEGER, "+
                            "AnalyticalAbilities INTEGER, "+
                            "Interpersonalskills INTEGER, "+
                            "DecisionMakingSkills INTEGER, "+
                            "SelfConfidence INTEGER, "+
                            "Creativity INTEGER, "+
                            "Punctualityregularity INTEGER, "+
                            "GeneralAwareness INTEGER, "+
                            "Commitment INTEGER, "+
                            "Hardwork INTEGER, "+

                            " PRIMARY KEY ( id ))"; 

                        newStmt.executeUpdate(sql1); 
                    }

                finally
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        if(newStmt!=null)
                            newStmt.close();
                    } 
                    catch (SQLException e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }



    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AdminHome.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AdminHome.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        try {
                if(rs!=null)
                    rs.close();
                if(stmt!=null)
                    stmt.close();
                if(connection!=null)
                    connection.close();                     
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i create 54 Statements in my code?How can i create a loop for that?

Comment: i need to create 54 tables

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend @ Ankur

Answer (score 5):

You are re-using the same Statement  for both queries. Don't do that; instead, create a new Statement object for each query.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new `statement` (a separate variable) to create a table. As result set is a `cursor` over statement object, it becomes invalid once you execute another `statement` on same object.

Comment: how can i create 54 `Statement`s in my code?How can i create a loop for that?

Comment: You will have to create a new statement object inside your rs.next loop and can close the statement after executing it. Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984783/why-is-while-rs-next-statement-ending-after-1st-iteration

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to create a new statement inside a while loop

Because you are executing a statement and overriding a statement with another query inside a while loop

That's why only first value is executing and remaining overriding.

Below is the modified code.

```
public void createTableStudent() {
    try {
        connection = (Connection) dbSource.getConnection();

        String qry = "SELECT studentName From batcha "; 
        System.out.println(qry);

        stmt = (PreparedStatement)  connection.prepareStatement(qry);
            rs =  stmt.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {



                String check=new String(rs.getString(("studentName")));
                String student = check.replaceAll("\\s","");

                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL_table, USER, PASS);
                Statement statement2 = connection.createStatement();

                String sql1 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+student+" " +
                    "(id INTEGER not NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, " +
                    " fcltyName VARCHAR(255), " + 

                    "CommunicationOral INTEGER, "+
                    "Communicationwritten INTEGER, "+
                    "Leadership INTEGER, "+
                    "AnalyticalAbilities INTEGER, "+
                    "Interpersonalskills INTEGER, "+
                    "DecisionMakingSkills INTEGER, "+
                    "SelfConfidence INTEGER, "+
                    "Creativity INTEGER, "+
                    "Punctualityregularity INTEGER, "+
                    "GeneralAwareness INTEGER, "+
                    "Commitment INTEGER, "+
                    "Hardwork INTEGER, "+

                    " PRIMARY KEY ( id ))"; 
                statement2.executeUpdate(sql1); 

                        }



    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AdminHome.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AdminHome.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

I remember reading that we should avoid using 'Create table if not exists'.Alternatively java.sql.DatabaseMetaData can be used to check if a table exists. The below link explains this.

http://somesimplethings.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/derby-create-table-if-not-exists.html

Comment: Please post relevant information here, external links might be dead in the future.